# How to draw the distribution of two variables?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, distribution

I'd like to draw the distribution of two variables with domains [-1,0,1]. I thought I could make box charts on the abscissa and ordinate axes, or a distribution function. I would like something like:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But this is a kernel smoothing technique to get the probability density function (PDF) of the 2D space that I found [here](https://github.com/tupui/HDR-Boxplot). So I would also be happy with:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Until now I had:

```
def plot_mean(columns_x, columns_y):
    try:
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
        plt.axis([-1, 1, -1, 1])     
        plt.grid(True) 
        plt.xlabel(columns_x)
        plt.ylabel(columns_y)
        # We get all parties from df_parties_means
        for party in df_parties_means['Party']:
                # we get the probability distribution function 
                party_x = df_parties_means.loc[
                    ((df_parties_means['Question'] == columns_x) & (df_parties_means['Party'] == party)), 'Mean']
                party_y = df_parties_means.loc[
                    ((df_parties_means['Question'] == columns_y) & (df_parties_means['Party'] == party)), 'Mean']
                # we plot the party related to the questions
                plt.scatter(party_x.values[0], party_y.values[0],
                        alpha=0.4, edgecolors='w',label = party)
                plt.text(party_x.values[0], party_y.values[0], party, fontsize=10)
        # We plot the people preferences
        plt.scatter(df_features[columns_x].mean( skipna = True), df_features[columns_y].mean( skipna = True),
            alpha=0.4, edgecolors='w')


        # plot the density function for the people preferences
        sns.kdeplot(df_features[columns_x], df_features[columns_y], ax=ax)
        print("x values:", df_features[columns_x].value_counts())
        print("y values:", df_features[columns_y].value_counts())
        sns.rugplot(df_features[columns_x], color="g", ax=ax)
        sns.rugplot(df_features[columns_y], vertical=True, ax=ax);
        plt.title('Perceptual map',y=1.05)
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        print(len(party_x))
        print(len(party_y))
        print("columns_x: ", columns_x)
        print("columns_y: ", columns_y)

import itertools

pairs = list(itertools.combinations(df_features.columns, 2))

[plot_mean(pair[0],pair[1]) for pair in pairs]
```

But it draws me:

[image]

Sometimes it shows me something from the distribution. I think it is when the data is balanced enough?

[image: ![enter image description here]

## Data for reproducible example

Mean of how the people perceive the parties:

```
>>>df_party_means

    mean    Question    Party
0   0.077083    Question1   Party1
1   -0.838896   Question1   Party2
2   0.931547    Question1   Party3
3   0.798064    Question1   Party4
4   -0.678798   Question1   Party5
5   0.960612    Question2   Party1
6   0.803926    Question2   Party2
7   0.586867    Question2   Party3
8   0.804372    Question2   Party4
9   0.346609    Question2   Party5
```

The answers of the people to the questions:

```
>>> df_features

    Question1   Question2
0   0   1
1   1   1
2   0   1
3   -1  1
4   -1  -1
5   -1  0
...
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without some data (see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but I can tell you at least that you are creating two figures unnecessarily. Move the line `f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))` to the top (just after the `try:`) and you should at least have only one figure.

Comment: @DizietAsahi Thanks, that helped :) I have added some data to make a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example